# how to add file attribute in flow and state in corda

Tags: corda

I am adding file as a attribute in flow and state in corda.It accept it but while making transaction it shows error."exception: Class "class java.io.File" is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable." like this.i add cordaSerialization annotation and implement Serializationwhitelist interface also.After deploying I got same error. Is it possible to add file as a attribute in flow and state in corda ??

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do with that `File`? Are you trying to add an attachment to your transaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use external methods by adding that code file to your code, you would need to add the annotation @CordaSerializable to the file. More details at https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/serialization.html#whitelisting

But it looks like you are trying to use the IO methods to attach the file to your corDapp. If that is the case, you need to upload your file to your node. You can learn about how to upload the file by this sample: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/attachment-sendfile
or https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/attachment-blacklist

(They are two way to do it.)

Comment: Do we have any way of uploading the attachments using the Corda RPC interface ? Any samples please?

Comment: There is an RPC upload method. you can see it by type ```run``` in the node shell